# Parse multiple arrays in subroutine

Tags: perl

I have the below code

```
    use strict;
    sub test {
       my($greeting, @names) = @_;
       my $returnString;

       foreach my $name (@names) {
           $returnString .= "$greeting, $name!\n";
       }

       return $returnString;
    }
    print &test("Hi", "Tim", "Tom", "Chris");
```

which outputs

```
    Hi Tim! Hi Tom! Hi Chris!
```

I want to be able to add multiple arrays. I tried modifying my code like the below

```
       my(@greeting, @names) = @_;
       print &test("Hi", "Tim", "Hello", "Tom", "Bye", "Chris");
```

However I have found that this can't be done.  From the reading I have done I think I need to pass the arguments as references.

```
        my($greeting, $names) = @_;
        my @names = $names;
```

But I have found this only outputs
        Hi Tim!

What is the best way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do need to pass them as references for the `sub` to receive them as two separate arrays rather than a single list, you just got the syntax wrong.  Try this instead:

```
my @greetings = qw( Hi Hello );
my @names = qw( Tim Tom Chris );

# Put a \ before the variable to get a reference to it
say_greetings(\@greetings, \@names);

sub say_greetings {
  my ($greeting_ref, $name_ref) = @_;

  # Put @ before an arrayref to get the array back
  my @greet = @$greeting_ref;
...
}
```

Also, you shouldn't get in the habit of prefixing `sub` calls with `&`.  It's a holdover from Perl 4.  In Perl 5, it's not required and can have unexpected side-effects.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to handle this situation depends on your needs. Here are several options:

1. `List::MoreUtils 'natatime'` (if order matters)

   ```
   use List::MoreUtils 'natatime';

   test( 'Hi', 'Tim', 'Hi', 'Tom' );

   sub test {

       warn( "Need to provide greeting-name pairs" ), # Check for
         return if @_ % 2;                            # data completeness

       my $iter = natatime, 2, @_;

       my $string;
       while ( my ( $greet, $name ) = $iter->() ) {

           $string .= "$greet $name!\n";
       }

       return $string;
   }
   ```
2. Treat the list passed as a hash (if order doesn't matter):

   ```
   test( 'Hi', 'Tim', 'Hi', 'Tom' );

   sub test {

       my %set = @_;  # warnings pragma checks for
                      # data completeness during runtime

       return join "\n", map { "$_ $set{$_}!" } keys %set;
   }
   ```
3. Pass key-value pairs as arrayrefs (preserves order, data completeness guaranteed):

   ```
   test( [ 'Hi', 'Tim' ], [ 'Hi', 'Tom' ] );

   sub test { join "\n", map { "@{$_}!" } @_ }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use references, pass your list as it is and iterate over every second element as greeting and name are set in pairs.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub test {
   my @arg = @_;

   my $returnString = "";
   foreach my $i (grep { ! ($_%2) } 0 .. $#arg) {

       my ($greeting, $name) = @arg[$i, $i+1];
       $returnString .= "$greeting, $name!\n";
   }

   return $returnString;
}

print test("Hi", "Tim", "Hello", "Tom", "Bye", "Chris");
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps. If the greeting and names are always in order then the following code works.

```
use strict;

test("Hi", "Tim", "Hello", "Tom", "Bye", "Chris");

sub test
{
        my $i;
        my $len = @_;

        for ($i = 0; $i < @_; $i += 2) {
                print "$_[$i] $_[$i + 1]\n"
        }
}
```

Input validation is not done. Check for array length to be multiple of 2 would be good to go.